# Lubuntu 20.04 cannot connect to any network after 1 year + of not using my computer

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager, ethernet

I was away from for over a year, and when I turned on my computer, I discovered that I could no longer connect to any networks. When I left the ethernet was working fine. All other devices in the house can connect without issues. These are the steps I have taken:

1. Checked the cables.
2. Checked the status of NetworkManager with `systemctl`. It was running, but I restarted it anywyway and that made no difference.
3. Tried connecting using wifi. I can see my wifi network and enter my password, but get a disconnect error after a few seconds of trying to connect.
4. Booted from a Lubuntu bootable USB. Wifi and ethernet both work right off the bat, websites loaded.
5. Checked my system time. If it's off, it's off by less than 1 minute.
6. After connecing with the bootable usb, when I restarted into my installation, wifi showed as connected (instead of "connecting" as it did before). However I could not load any pages or ping anything (even my router). After restarting again, all I have seen is the behavior described in #3.

I'm at somewhat of a loss as to what to try next. The usual stuff isn't working.

addendum: Here is a sample of `journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` output`

```
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1165] policy: auto-activating connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' (f3bef4ef-9f4d-471d-9288-835949887f58)
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1171] device (wlp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' (f3bef4ef-9f4d-471d-9288-835949887f58)
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1173] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1177] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1181] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1185] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MYWIFINWTWORK' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1185] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1187] sup-iface[0x5604bb5e1920,wlp5s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1217] device (wlp5s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1221] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1224] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1225] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MYWIFINWTWORK'
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1225] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1225] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1225] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1226] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1226] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1340] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 12 22:01:07 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090467.1340] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 12 22:01:32 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <warn>  [1634090492.1007] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Oct 12 22:01:32 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090492.1007] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:32 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090492.1012] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 12 22:01:32 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <warn>  [1634090492.1026] device (wlp5s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK'
Oct 12 22:01:32 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090492.1029] device (wlp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:32 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090492.1044] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:01:32 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090492.1044] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9290] policy: auto-activating connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' (f3bef4ef-9f4d-471d-9288-835949887f58)
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9296] device (wlp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' (f3bef4ef-9f4d-471d-9288-835949887f58)
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9298] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9302] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9308] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9312] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MYWIFINWTWORK' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9312] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9315] sup-iface[0x5604bb5e1920,wlp5s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9343] device (wlp5s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9350] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9353] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9354] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MYWIFINWTWORK'
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9354] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9354] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9354] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9355] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9355] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9463] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Oct 12 22:01:58 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090518.9463] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Oct 12 22:01:59 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090519.1292] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:01:59 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090519.1292] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:02:09 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090529.1349] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 12 22:02:09 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090529.1350] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 12 22:02:09 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090529.9928] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 12 22:02:09 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090529.9929] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Oct 12 22:02:10 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090530.1647] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:02:10 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090530.1648] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:02:20 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090540.1716] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 12 22:02:20 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090540.1716] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 12 22:02:24 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <warn>  [1634090544.1004] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Oct 12 22:02:24 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090544.1004] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:02:24 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090544.1009] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 12 22:02:24 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <warn>  [1634090544.1020] device (wlp5s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK'
Oct 12 22:02:24 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090544.1024] device (wlp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:02:24 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090544.9327] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:02:24 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090544.9327] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9466] policy: auto-activating connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' (f3bef4ef-9f4d-471d-9288-835949887f58)
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9473] device (wlp5s0): Activation: starting connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' (f3bef4ef-9f4d-471d-9288-835949887f58)
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9474] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9480] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9486] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9492] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'MYWIFINWTWORK' has security, but secrets are required.
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9492] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9496] sup-iface[0x5604bb5e1920,wlp5s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9530] device (wlp5s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9536] device (wlp5s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9539] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9539] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MYWIFINWTWORK'
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9539] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9539] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9539] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK'
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9539] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9540] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9641] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9642] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9977] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 12 22:02:50 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090570.9978] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Oct 12 22:02:51 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090571.1163] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Oct 12 22:02:51 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090571.1163] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <warn>  [1634090580.1538] sup-iface[0x5604bb5e1920,wlp5s0]: connection disconnected (reason 2)
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090580.1588] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090580.1597] device (wlp5s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090580.1598] device (wlp5s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090580.1602] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> disconnected
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <warn>  [1634090580.1618] device (wlp5s0): no secrets: No agents were available for this request.
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090580.1618] device (wlp5s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090580.1623] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <warn>  [1634090580.1632] device (wlp5s0): Activation: failed for connection 'MYWIFINWTWORK'
Oct 12 22:03:00 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090580.1636] device (wlp5s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 12 22:03:01 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090581.2593] device (wlp5s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Oct 12 22:03:01 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634090581.2594] device (p2p-dev-wlp5s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
```

Also I checked `journalctl` again after again trying to plug in my ethernet and bring it up with `ip link set`. I'm not sure if it is relevant or not.

```
Oct 12 19:18:30 virtland kernel: igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: renamed from eth0
Oct 12 19:18:35 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634080715.3773] manager: (enp4s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Oct 13 00:28:49 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634099329.6246] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="95ca1a5d-7e4c-4a9e-9581-e600b3e40c24" name="Ethernet connection 1" pid=19985 uid=1000 result="fail" reason="Connection 'Ethernet connection 1' is not available on device enp4s0 because device is strictly unmanaged"
Oct 13 00:53:24 virtland sudo[275807]:     boss : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/boss ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ip link set enp4s0 up
Oct 13 00:53:24 virtland systemd-networkd[1541]: enp4s0: Link UP
Oct 13 00:53:26 virtland kernel: igb 0000:04:00.0 enp4s0: igb: enp4s0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX
Oct 13 00:53:26 virtland kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
Oct 13 00:53:26 virtland systemd-networkd[1541]: enp4s0: Gained carrier
Oct 13 00:53:26 virtland NetworkManager[5959]: <info>  [1634100806.9401] device (enp4s0): carrier: link connected
Oct 13 00:53:28 virtland avahi-daemon[5951]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::7285:c2ff:fe65:9f1b.
Oct 13 00:53:28 virtland avahi-daemon[5951]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Oct 13 00:53:28 virtland systemd-networkd[1541]: enp4s0: Gained IPv6LL
Oct 13 00:53:28 virtland avahi-daemon[5951]: Registering new address record for fe80::7285:c2ff:fe65:9f1b on enp4s0.*.
Oct 13 00:53:39 virtland sudo[276134]:     boss : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/boss ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/ip link set enp4s0 up
```

UPDATE: It all works now! Problem is, I have no idea why as I changed absolutely no configurations. All I did is leave the computer off for a couple hours.

I rebooted and the wifi interface came up and connected, but then disconnected.

```
boss@virtland:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.30 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=2.01 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=4.40 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=5.89 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=2.47 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=2.51 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=40.1 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=63 time=9.10 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=12 ttl=63 time=3.88 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 9 received, 25% packet loss, time 11044ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.005/8.075/40.126/11.531 ms
boss@virtland:~$ sudo ip link set enp4s0 up^C
boss@virtland:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.251.35.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=20.2 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=11.1 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=25.0 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=7.98 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=11.3 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=6 ttl=117 time=14.3 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=7 ttl=117 time=29.9 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=8 ttl=117 time=31.6 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=9 ttl=117 time=14.1 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=11 ttl=117 time=15.6 ms
From virtland (10.0.0.23) icmp_seq=31 Destination Host Unreachable
From virtland (10.0.0.23) icmp_seq=32 Destination Host Unreachable
From virtland (10.0.0.23) icmp_seq=33 Destination Host Unreachable
From virtland (10.0.0.23) icmp_seq=34 Destination Host Unreachable
From virtland (10.0.0.23) icmp_seq=38 Destination Host Unreachable
From virtland (10.0.0.23) icmp_seq=41 Destination Host Unreachable
From virtland (10.0.0.23) icmp_seq=42 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
45 packets transmitted, 10 received, +7 errors, 77.7778% packet loss, time 44801ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.978/18.107/31.643/7.808 ms, pipe 4
boss@virtland:~$
```

When the interface comes up again (without any intervention)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000              
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00                                                
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                                                                       
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                           
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host                                                                             
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                           
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000                  
    link/ether 70:85:c2:65:9f:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                   
3: enp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000      
    link/ether 70:85:c2:65:9f:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                   
4: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000     
    link/ether 28:c6:3f:15:64:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                   
    inet 10.0.0.23/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp5s0                           
       valid_lft 86319sec preferred_lft 86319sec                                                         
    inet6 fe80::1347:560:8ccd:7267/64 scope link noprefixroute                                           
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                                           
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000 
    link/ether 52:54:00:3d:df:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                                                   
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

I tried plugging the ethernet in again (this time to a different port) and bringing up ip with `ip link set`. This time it seems to have worked. What is odd though is that the applet icon still shows that I am disconnected. I suspect my problems may not be over.

```
boss@virtland:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:65:9f:1b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:85:c2:65:9f:19 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.7/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic enp6s0
       valid_lft 86224sec preferred_lft 86224sec
    inet6 fe80::7285:c2ff:fe65:9f19/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:c6:3f:15:64:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:3d:df:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:3d:df:24 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
boss@virtland:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (142.250.80.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=10.7 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=13.5 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=4.89 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=10.0 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=5 ttl=117 time=12.7 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=6 ttl=117 time=15.0 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=7 ttl=117 time=5.72 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=8 ttl=117 time=8.78 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=9 ttl=117 time=10.9 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=10 ttl=117 time=3.92 ms
64 bytes from lga34s34-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.80.46): icmp_seq=11 ttl=117 time=5.95 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
11 packets transmitted, 11 received, 0% packet loss, time 10017ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.920/9.277/14.969/3.560 ms
```

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator thanks, I have added those logs.

Comment: @bobcat I did not have to set the date, it was correct when I checked it. Also, wouldn't a dead battery prevent me from booting?

Comment: @bobcat but if my battery were dead, wouldn't it have forgotten the date entirely? If it is off, it is off by less than a minute.

Comment: @bobcat how would I know that? My Motherboard is an ASRock x399 Taichi, I don't see anything related to the battery in BIOS or manual. According to `sensors` the battery is "ok".